# 'LocalSqlServer' was not found in the applications configuration after conversion from VB.NET to C#.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, connection-string

I have a site that I've converted from VB.NET to C#.NET and every time I run this site in C#.NET, I get the following error:

**Parser Error Message: The connection name 'LocalSqlServer' was not found in the applications configuration or the connection string is empty.**

Source Error:

```
<membership>
    <providers>
        <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" 
             type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" 
             connectionStringName="LocalSqlServer" 
             enablePasswordRetrieval="false" 
             enablePasswordReset="true" 
             requiresQuestionAndAnswer="true" 
             applicationName="/" 
             requiresUniqueEmail="false" 
             passwordFormat="Hashed" 
             maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" 
             minRequiredPasswordLength="7" 
             minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="1" 
             passwordAttemptWindow="10" 
             passwordStrengthRegularExpression=""/>
    </providers>
</membership>
```

The weird thing is that I don't get this error if I run the original VB.NET site. I get this error only when I run the C#.NET site.

Both site has identical web.config files and machine.config file can't be wrong since it works with VB.NET site. Is there anything I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have an entry called LocalSqlServer in your connectionStrings section of the web config?  Is the case the same for the key?  Is there a backslash in it?

Comment: I don't have LocalSqlServer in connectionStrings section of my web.config.

Answer (score 0):

There is a trick....

Seems Web Forms app with membership "hides" this from you.  You need to do the following:

```
 <remove name="LocalSqlServer" />
 <add name="LocalSqlServer" connectionString="Data Source=YourServer;Initial Catalog=YourDB;Integrated Security=true"
  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Or at the very least run the first line to remove the "current" one.

Comment: I added the both line in my web.config and I basically get Sql server not found error. When I run the first line only, I still get the same original error.

Comment: You must have a database running in our near your old app that has your membership info in (it will have application, users, membership, profile - and may be prefixed by aspnet_).  You need to copy that over.  It may be in your app_data folder.  Alternatively, you need to recreate a new one using aspnet_regsql.exe (search for that one)